# Linking another library from C-library in gwan/libraries results in "undefined symbol" error

Tags: g-wan

I'm trying to use a standard library libuuid inside my C-library file my_uuid.c:

gwan/libraries/my_uuid.c:

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>
#pragma link "uuid"
void my_uuid_generate(uuid_t uuid)
{
  uuid_generate(uuid);
}
```

gwan/init.c:

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>
#pragma link "uuid"
#pragma link "libraries/my_uuid.c"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  uuid_t uuid;
  my_uuid_generate(uuid);
  return 0;
}
```

However, G-Wan fails to start and prints such message:

> Linking ./init.c: undefined symbol: uuid_generate

This mustn't be the problem of libuuid installation or non-standard path, because such servlet does work successfully:

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>
#pragma link "uuid"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   uuid_t uuid;
   char str[256];

   uuid_generate(uuid);
   uuid_unparse(uuid, str);
   printf("%s\n", str);

   xbuf_cat(get_reply(argv), "Hello, World!");
   return 200;
}
```

The problem might be due to that G-Wan first loads init.c and then my_uuid.c instead of libuuid, even though I have #pragma link "uuid" in init.c.

Does anybody know how to solve the problem?
Is it considered valid to link other libraries from C-file libraries in gwan/libraries?

Comment: "C-file libraries" as you call them were not an intended way to use G-WAN, hence my reply below. Further, dynamic linking has an overhead (memory, cache lines, CPU caches) which means you should only use it for large libraries which size will disqualify directly linked object code as it may be duplicated if used by several G-WAN scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, G-Wan successfully started when I moved #pragma link "uuid" below the #pragma link "libraries/my_uuid.c" in init.c file:

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>
#pragma link "libraries/my_uuid.c"
#pragma link "uuid"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  uuid_t uuid;
  my_uuid_generate(uuid);
  return 0;
}
```

Definitely, it changed the order in which G-Wan loads libuuid and my_uuid.c. Now it first loads libuuid (with uuid_generate() symbol) and then my_uuid.c (with my_uuid_generate() symbol, which in turn calls uuid_generate()).

Gil, do I correctly understand that currently G-Wan is not designed to provide a controllable order of library loads? Can the G-Wan team consider updating the G-Wan server to load the libraries in a controllable/predicatable order, at least in some extent? I.e. load the dependencies before the dependency users.
For example we should be able to write such code as below and the G-Wan server to load first libuuid, then my_uuid.c, then init.c:

gwan/libraries/my_uuid.c:

```
#pragma link "uuid"
```

gwan/init.c:

```
#pragma link "libraries/my_uuid.c"
```

(notice no #pragma link "uuid" in init.c)

Comment: I don't think GWAN has much control over loading of libraries (or their order). It simply hands off the ".C" files to the compiler/linker (separately or together depending on OS/environment and other factors). The compiler extracts the pragma/linker options and inserts them on the command line of the linker.

Comment: The [curl example](http://gwan.com/developers) given on their site talks nothing about puttting bootstrapping code in init.c file.

Answer (score 1):

I read GWAN's documentation. If you write your own library, you should be able to integrate well with it (treating it as a preexisting library).

```
myuuid.h
myuuid.c
```

Then generate your library, by compiling myuuid.c:

```
libmyuuid.a
```

Put the library as gwan/libraries/libuuid.a and try it as below.

```
#include "myuuid.h"
#pragma link "./libraries/myuuid"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    my_uuid_generate();
    return 0;
}
```

You may want to keep an eye on gwan/logs/gwan.log file to see if the link worked. You could also start GWAN server in a terminal, manually, to look at the errors.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it also only works if I put #pragma link "uuid" at the end of init.c file (similarly as in my last answer), otherwise it fails with same error "Linking ./init.c: undefined symbol: uuid_generate".

Answer (score 0):

The `servlet` works because you are linking your script directly to an existing library (already compiled code).

The `init.c` script fails to link because the `"#pragma link "libraries/my_uuid.c"` library that calls a compiled library does not exist yet (it's still source code).

You should rather use `#include "libraries/my_uuid.c"` in `init.c` to have this kind of constructions work.

Comment: If my_uuid.c doesn't yet exist as a binary, I'd expect init.c to fail on my_uuid_generate(), but it fails on uuid_generate() - what should mean my_uuid.c has been translated into binary library. Am I right? If I'm wrong, how does linker know about uuid_generate() call from not-yet-translated-into-binary my_uuid.c?